# Não existe o arquivo vs_setup.msi, como eu faço

Tags: c#, visual-studio, services

Uso o VS2017. A opção **Other Project** não existe. Tive que baixar uma extensão, instalar, para poder ter essa opção, pois estou fazendo um serviço windows e necessitarei de instalar esse serviço. Quando porem tento montar o instalador, ele procura esse path: **c:\232379996f253b2e143a9449\1046_PTB_LP\redist\VisualStudioShell\VSIntSetup** e nesse path o arquivo **vs_setup.msi**. Dei um find no meu disco C:\ e não encontrei o arquivo. O que devo fazer? O erro é **1706**, que não consegue localizar um pacote de instalação e se refere ao VS2010

Comment: não seria mais fácil desinstalar tudo e reinstalar?

Comment: @ItaloRodrigo, fiz isso duas vezes. Não sei o que está acontecendo.

Comment: Tem certeza que reinstalou tudo? O Visual Studio é considerado uma ferramenta do Windows e deixa muito "vestígio" para trás.

Comment: https://goo.gl/t2GqZE olha isso

Comment: @GabrielColetta, sim gabriel.